# how to overlay audio on video - .flv files

Tags: audio, video, flv

I have lecture videos in .flv format and its corresponding sound in another .flv format file. Is there a way to overlay the sound file onto the video and save it?

Please advise.

Comment: Any video editing software should be able to do that provided it supports the source(s) file type(s). What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried HitFilmExpress. and it doesn't support FLV. This is why RTFM is so important. Sigh!. Anyway it also looks like flv type is not that popular as other formats for video editing stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

A multi-platform free program known as [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) allows direct import of FLV files and can handle at least three video streams for simultaneous edit/composition.

I have the windows version (win7x64) and tested this by loading two different files into the editor window.

You can split off the audio from either file and add it to the desired video stream. If required, you can break and split along the timeline to ensure audio synchronizes with your video.

Directly from the above site:

> Multi-track video editing
>
> Kdenlive allows you to use and arrange several audio and video tracks,
>   each one can be locked or muted to your convenience.

[image: timeline]